# How to make a bat file to abort itself if not finished in x seconds

Tags: batch-file, timeout, exit

How to make a bat file to abort itself if not finished in x seconds.

In this script, some operation gets stuck sometimes, and I wish the whole script to exit(1) if it takes more than x seconds

Comment: You would have to launch a second script that monitors the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a Monitoring process at start of your Bat.
You have to set a **Title** for the process that will be killed after X seconds.

```
@echo on

::The Endtime in seconds
set "$Time=5"

::The title of the process to kill after [Endtime]
set "$Title=test"

title %$Title%

::Generating the monitoring process
(
echo timeout %$Time%
echo taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %$Title%" /T) >timer.bat

::Running the monitoring Process in another thread
start timer.bat


::Here come your code

Pause
```

I just putted `pause` to simulate your code replace it with your code.

Comment: I can actually use this logic for a run-as-user script I have. Thanks!